# How could I estimate the total global environmental impact of WWII?

Tags: world-war-two

I've been long wondering, and pondering this question since I've been studying and researching WWII for the last 15 years.

I know this is an impossible calculation to make, but I wonder if anyone has any idea how I might come to some fact or figure on the total environmental impact of WWII.  When I research this, what comes up usually, is just the atomic bombings of Japan.  But, i'm interested in more of the long-term effects.  For example, here is a list of some of the items I've been trying to quantify.

- How much lead is in the ground, from the ~180 billion small arms fired, that is now leaching into the groundwater?
- How much lead is leaching into the ocean water from the war in the Pacific?
- How much oil was spilled into the ocean from all of the merchant shipping sunk in the Atlantic, coupled with all of the oil from the U-Boats that were sunk.
- How much heavy metal contamination is entering the oceans from things onboard those sunken vessels, like the lead in the batteries in the U-Boats?
- How much CO<sup>2</sup>, and other toxins that might still be measurable today was released into the atmosphere from all of the fuel that was burned to fly 1,000 plane formations over Germany, and Japan, and to fuel the "Red Ball Express", not to mention all of the tanks, from all sides, ships, trucks, guns, trains, etc.
- How much pollution and other toxins that might still be measurable today was released by all of the cities that the Allies burned to the ground?  The 16 square miles of Tokyo, in a single raid that killed more people and did more damage than Little Boy did in Hiroshima.  Add to that, Dresden, and all of the other cities destroyed by firestorms.  Those fires had to release thousands of tons of toxins in the air?
- All of the fires from the scorched earth policy employed by both Hitler, and Stalin.

All of that doesn't even take into the account all of the pollution that manufacturing all the weapons of war added as well.  My interest lies in the lasting damage that was done, and what effects it might still be having on the Pacific and Atlantic oceans.  All of that cargo didn't just disappear.  It is still there, slowly decaying, and leaking oils, fuels, grease, and who knows what else.  Not only from the delivery (Liberty) ships, but from the cargo as well.  In the Pacific, all those carriers, battleships, and cruisers, that went down, with all of the HE on board, all of the lead ammo, all of the fuel, and oils on in the planes.  It's actually mind-boggling when you think about it.  Or... Am I wrong?  Are the oceans simply *that* big, that when you combine everything that ever went down into the ocean, it is just not enough to have a measurable effect of the wildlife, quality of the water, etc?

Japan is a really good example of how Mother Nature heals herself.  But there still has to be some sort of measurable impact of WWII that remains still, to this day, doesn't there?

I realize that coming to some solid numbers is probably an impossible task.  But, best-guesses, and estimates, backed by solid evidence and facts would be fantastic.

Comment: Hi LarryF and welcome to History SE. This looks very broad as you are covering a lot of different sources / kinds of pollution. I think you need to narrow it down...P.S. I'm not the downvoter, but maybe whoever it is feels the same way (?)

Comment: and how do offset the negatives from the positives of greatly reduced population in many areas, thus less industrial and agricultural load in the years after the war.

Comment: I don't think there is a generally accepted method of estimating the environmental impact of _anything_.  I think you're asking for new research in economics to be conducted and then applied to history. It is going to be difficult to identify an authoritative answer.

Comment: You bring up a single event, the Tokyo fire bombing, with 16 sq miles on fire. Currently *one* of the fires burning in California covers 119 sq miles, and estimates from *3500 to 7000 sq miles* burned in the Amazon this summer.  If you are interested in doing some of the math on the effects, look into [Atmospheric dispersion modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_dispersion_modeling).

Comment: A recent study mentioned  [here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/04/180430102522.htm) has begun looking into the effects of munitions on marine environments, but notice the title of the page.  The answers you are looking for are Science, not History.

Comment: That was a relatively less industrialized era. We probably generate more radioactive waste and put more human-generated CO2 into the atmosphere worldwide every year today than was released that entire war. Realize there are almost 4x as many human beings on this planet as there were then as well.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not to mention that, had WWII never hapened, we would by now be 5x more instead of 4x more compared to 1939 levels, polluting even more than we are today. On the other hand, US would have a smaller impact on western European's lifestyle, and the European society would have remained less polluting during the 1950s.

Comment: As far as I understand, nobody tried to give quantitative estimates of the items you mention. So go ahead and try to do it yourself. But my prediction is this: you will find that the effect is negligible. I mean our civilization makes a great impact on the environment. But our wars make little difference.It is our "normal" daily life which makes most of this impact.

Comment: Thank you each for the great comments and feedback on this question.  Since it has been placed on hold, and I'm not quite sure I can simplify it to a level that is suitable for the History SE, I think I will abandon this question entirely, and perhaps bring it up in Science instead.  I'm sorry if I wasted anyone's time with this question; but just know that you comments will not be wasted on me!  I truly thank you guys, you've given me a lot to think about!  I am a true history lover, (some may say, "nerd", lol) so I hope my future posts will be much more productive.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you might find "Aftermath: The Remnants of War" by Donovan Webster at least tangentially interesting. It deals with such things as unexploded ordinance left over from the world wars (and more recent conflicts).